# Permutations of not selecting the right size of dress for 3 daughters

Tags: permutations

I am trying to solve the following problem and the answer I am getting is (6 - 1) = 5 but the answer is given as 2.

**Problem**

A father purchased dress for his 3 daughters. The dresses are of same color but different size and they are kept in dark room. In how many ways all the 3 daughters will not choose their own dress?

**Question**

Is my logic in below solution missing something or may be my solution is correct but the answer given in book is  wrong?

**My Solution**

Total number of ways of selecting dresses = number of ways of selecting wrong sizes + number of ways of selecting the correct sizes

Using symbols, the above equation becomes
 t = w + c

We need to determine w, which we can by knowing t and c.
t= 3! = 6
c = 1 since there is only one correct way of each daughter selecting the correct size.

Therefore,
6 = w + 1

so, w = 5

So, there are 5 ways in which the daughters can select the wrong dress according to my logic. **BUT the answer given is 2.**

Comment: Hint: There are only 2 ways that _all 3_ daughters can get the wrong dress. In some of your solutions 1 daughter gets the right dress & her sisters get each other's dress. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: Ok. I get it. In my solution w includes where 1 or 2 daughters get the correct dress but 2 or 1 get the wrong dress. Thanks for that

Comment: You still getting it wrong. If 2 girls get correct dress. Then its obvious that 3rd girl also gets correct. Subtract cases with 1 girl gets correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint -

You are skipping the cases one daughter select right dress.

Subtract that also.

So we have 5 - 3 = 2

Comment: If any doubt please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Let the daughters be $A,B,C$ their right dresses be $d_A,d_B,d_C$

If $A$ selects $d_B,B$ has to select $d_C,C$ has to $C_A$

If $A$ selects $d_C,B$ has to select $d_A,C$ has to $C_B$

Possible dress selections :

$$\{A,d_A;B,d_B;C,d_C\}$$

$$\{A,d_A;B,d_C;C,d_B\}$$

$$\{A,d_B;B,d_C;C,d_A\}$$

$$\{A,d_B;B,d_A;C,d_C\}$$

$$\{A,d_C;B,d_A;C,d_B\}$$

$$\{A,d_C;B,d_B;C,d_A\}$$

The third & fifth are all wrong selections